# Is it possible that angular/nativescript databinding wouldn't work under specific circumstances?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular7

I'm using telerik's nativescript-ui-chart plugin in my nativescript/angular application and i've bumped into an odd issue: upon using an instance of a RadPieChart inside of a RadListView, and by trying to style the chart's sections in normal and selected states, like below

```
<Palette tkPiePalette seriesState="Normal" seriesName="orders">
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[0]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[1]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[2]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[3]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[4]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>   
</Palette>

<Palette tkPiePalette seriesState="Selected" seriesName="orders">
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[0]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[1]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[2]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[3]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>
    <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry [fillColor]="chartDataIterable[4]?.color" strokeColor="Transparent" strokeWidth="0"></PaletteEntry>   
</Palette>
```

The angular data binding on the fillColor property would work only on whichever palette was positioned phisically higher in the html file. This behaviour is really strange and i would like to learn what caused it, also because the exact same component will behave as expected when used outside of the RadListView. I found a workaround to this issue, but i'm really curious as to what could be causing the data binding to work like that

Comment: can you reproduce this in playground?

Comment: @Narendra sadly i couldn't even get the chart to show up inside of a list view in there, here's the link to the playgorund: [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WP0Jap)